# DOID , SYMP Ontology Sparql Queries

Tags: wikidata, sparql, ontology, semantic-web

I need to extract the list of diseases, categories, bodyparts and symptoms.
I've found several ontologies for that datasets.
Disease ontology, symptom ontology,  Bioportal and Wikipedia. But I don't know how to build  SPARQL queries correctly for extracting needed information.
Is there anyone that can help?

Comment: HTH: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Diseases

Comment: That  is not what I need.  I couldn't get  the relationship  from WIKIDATA.

Comment: So maybe first describe which data sources you want to use, and point us to their documentation.

Comment: @VladimirAlexiev I am looking for anyone which can give me  needed information.

Comment: Please be more precise: give us some links to the datasets you mentioned, and a bit more detail on what you want to extract. Eg "Body parts" of whose anatomy, humans or other species?